# RxJava: Using SubscribeOn makes the program exit without completing

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

This is my sample code

```
Observable.range(1,5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .map(Observables05::doSomething)
            .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("done"));
```

My doSomething Method is,

```
public static int doSomething(int i) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Processing " + i +
                " on Thread -- " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return i;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Using only the sample code in my main thread simply exits the program. However, if `Thread.sleep(3000)` is used after this then program works correctly before exiting when the sleep time ends.

Is this the expected behaviour and why? How can I made this code run without using `Thread.sleep`?

Answer (score 3):

`subscribeOn` schedules `subscribe` call to background thread (you have selected `computation` scheduler). After this scheduling your main thread is free to go, i.e. terminate your program.

Somehow you need to wait for all desirable tasks to complete before exiting. `Thread.sleep(3000)` does the job for simple test cases.

Real programs usually do not terminate that fast. Still there are cases when you need to wait for some background task to complete. There are various thread synchronization mechanisms (eg. `CountDownLatch`) that you can use for that.

Comment: Does this happen because the background threads are running as deamons?

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior. Simple solution for you as you're executing in `main` method is to use `toBlocking()` before you subscribe - as below -

```
    Observable.range(1,5)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(DummyJunk::doSomething)
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("done"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the code that you have written make use of the [TestSubscriber](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html).

Code would look like this:

```
TestSubscriber<Integer> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

Observable.range(1,5)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(Observables05::doSomething)
        .subscribe(testSubscriber);

testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Keep in mind that `TestSubscriber` allows you to test a lot more than only terminal event.